# what is the best way to IPC with FFMPEG On windows

Tags: windows, sockets, ffmpeg, ipc

I have a client and a server code. I create ffmpeg process on
both ends and use pipes to communicate with ffmpeg. I passed an RGB data and read HVec out , send that the client and do the opposite. basically I'm streaming HVec, The problem I have  with the pipes is The buffer size are too small so I have to do a bunch of file read operations from the pipe . and it's really slows me down. for example if I have to read 100 bytes , function reads 20 bytes.  so I have to loop five times to read hundred bytes .  of course these numbers are made up . actual data size I try to Read is 1080*1920*4=829400
1 is writing to a socket and communicating via sockets a better choice. 
2 would name pipes work better?

I know third option is to use avcodec lib but I'm trying not to do that